# Async forEachOfLimit function not limiting iteration for collection

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

My Question is - **async.forEachLimit** function is not limiting the iteration for n number of times.

I am execute async task for my collection. I have tried this...

```
var async = require('async');
console.log(finalLocations.length); //Expecting 4
```

So I need to execute the loop for 3 times as I am using current value to the key and next value to the key in same operation. It will lead to undefined for the last iteration.

As I am iteration for 1 less time the length of collection. I used this. If length is 4 I want to iterate it for 3 times that would be 0,1,2. this way -

```
async.forEachOfLimit(finalLocations, finalLocations.length - 2, function (value, key, next) {

    console.log(key + ': ' + value);

    //distanceMatrix.matrix(finalLocations[key], finalLocations[key + 1], function (err, successiveDistances) {
    //    if (err) return next(err);
    //    if (!successiveDistances || successiveDistances.status !== 'OK') {
    //        return next({status: 400, message: 'No distance'});
    //    }
    //
    //    if (successiveDistances.rows[0].elements[0].status === 'OK') {
    //        totalTime = totalTime + successiveDistances.rows[0].elements[0].duration.value;
    //        totalDistance = totalDistance + successiveDistances.rows[0].elements[0].distance.value;
    //    }
    //    next();
    //});
    next();
}, function (err) {
    console.error('Printing error here :- ' + err);
    if (err) return callback(err);

    console.log('Successfully completed all iterations !!');
    callback(null, {totalTime: 0, totalDistance: 0});
});
```

Or if simple I can post.

```
async.forEachOfLimit([1,2,3,4], 2, function (value, key, next) {
    console.log(key + ': ' + value); 
    next();
}, function (err) {
    console.error('Printing error here :- ' + err);
    if (err) return callback(err);

    console.log('Successfully completed all iterations !!');
    callback(null, {totalTime: 0, totalDistance: 0});
});
```

Its console is :

```
0: 1
1: 2
2: 3
3: 4
Printing error here :- null
Successfully completed all iterations !!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`async.forEachOfLimit()` iterates the entire collection you pass it.  The 2nd argument (the limit value) is only specifying how many iterations to have in flight at the same time.  So, if you pass it an array of 4 elements and a limit of 3, it will start the first 3 operations, then when one of them finishes, it will start the fourth.

That's how that function is coded to work.

If you only want to iterate part of the collection, you can splice off a partial copy of the collection and pass that to something like `async.each()`.

Comment: Ok. I need to add an intermediate spliced array and then process that. Thanks.